# Why might setting Outlook.MailItem.HTMLBody be slow?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an add-in that has is modifying the HTML body of a message like so:

```
internal LoggingData ProcessMessage(ref Outlook.MailItem oMail)
{
    // Code that creates myNewHTML from oMail.HTMLBody

    Debug.WriteLog("start");
    oMail.HTMLBody = myNewHTML;
    Debug.WriteLog("stop");
}
```

And my logs show that the timestamps between the `start` and `stop` messages can be upwards of 30 seconds.

What might be happening in the assignment that might be slowing things down and how can I speed it up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what the content of the myNewHTML variable is? What kind of message store are you using? What is the Outlook version?

Keep in mind that Outlook validates your HTML and updates the RTF and plain text versions of the body as well.

Comment: We see the problem across a variety of message sizes and outlook versions. But it only affects a small percentage of users.

Comment: What could make validating the HTML and updating the RTF and plain text versions slow? Does it have to access the network? Spin up a background application?

Comment: No, it does not do any of these to the best of my knowledge. Are you using multiple threads at all?

Comment: Yes, we do have a thread that runs a dialog box to display progress.

Comment: OOM = Outlook Object Model.

Comment: The dialog box runs in a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` that is kicked off from the `ADXOlItemSend_EventHandler` hook.  Also, I'm actually asking this on behalf of a colleague who wants to know if it would be faster to set it using Redemption to set the HTML body?

Comment: Is your code a standalone exe or a COM addin? In the former case, all secondary threads will be marshaled to the main Outlook thread anyway. In the latter case, Outlook 2013 will raise an exception. Redemption might be faster, but only testing can tell.